# REST API Client cache

Tags: .net, rest

I'm developing a static site builder that gets its data from various APIs in our landscape (eg. Gitlab API, Docker Registry API, ...) and builds MkDocs from that.

I want the builder to be stateless, so currently it's calling all these APIs all the time (~500 for every run). Besides becoming tediously slow to develop, I m also hitting 429s, etc.

How could I solve this? What I am thinking

- either there is a built-in option in .NET's `HttpClient` that I have not discovered yet
- either I need to set up some sort of local proxy on my machine and instead of going to api.gitlab.com to localhost:1234 or something
- ...?

The cache must survive restarts and ideally, I would like to have granular control to flush the cache and/or retention policies.

Any advice or options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with reverse proxy tools like Charles, Fiddler, Squid and Varnish but did not get anywhere.

I ended up writing my own caching handler based on @guru-stron's last suggestion.

```cs
var cacheDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "HttpClientCache");
var cacheExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

// Create an HttpClient with CacheHandler
var cacheHandler = new CacheHandler(cacheDirectory, cacheExpiration);     
var httpClient = new HttpClient(cacheHandler);

// Send an HTTP request using the HttpClient
var requestUri = new Uri("https://api.example.com/data");
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
```

When an HTTP request is sent, the CacheHandler first checks if there's a valid cache file available for the requested resource. If the cache file exists and hasn't expired, the cached response is returned. Otherwise, the request is sent to the server, and the response is saved in the cache for future use. The cache is organized in a directory structure, and cache files are named based on the query parameters of the request to ensure unique cache files for each request. The cache's expiration time can be customized, and the cache is stored as JSON files on the file system.

```
class CacheHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string cacheDirectory;
    private readonly TimeSpan cacheExpiration;

    public CacheHandler(string cacheDirectory, TimeSpan cacheExpiration, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler = null)
        : base(innerHandler ?? new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        this.cacheDirectory = cacheDirectory;
        this.cacheExpiration = cacheExpiration;
        if (!Directory.Exists(this.cacheDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(this.cacheDirectory);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cacheFolderPath = GenerateCacheFolderPath(request.RequestUri);
        var cacheFileName = GenerateCacheFileName(request.RequestUri);
        var cacheFilePath = Path.Combine(cacheFolderPath, cacheFileName);

        // If the cache file exists and is not expired, return the cached response
        if (File.Exists(cacheFilePath) && IsCacheValid(cacheFilePath))
        {
            var cachedResponse = await ReadResponseFromFileAsync(cacheFilePath, cancellationToken);
            return cachedResponse;
        }

        // Otherwise, send the request and cache the response
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            await WriteResponseToFileAsync(response, cacheFilePath, cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;

        string GenerateCacheFolderPath(Uri uri)
        {
            var domain = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.Host);

            var encodedPath = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(),
                uri.Segments.Take(uri.Segments.Length - 1).Select(segment => Uri.EscapeDataString(segment.TrimEnd('/'))));
            if (Path.IsPathRooted(encodedPath))
                encodedPath = encodedPath.TrimStart(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

            var endpoint = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.Segments.Last().TrimEnd('/'));

            var cacheFolderPath = Path.Combine(cacheDirectory, domain, encodedPath, endpoint);
            if (!Directory.Exists(cacheFolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(cacheFolderPath);
            }

            return cacheFolderPath;
        }

        string GenerateCacheFileName(Uri uri)
        {
            var queryString = uri.Query.Length > 0 ? Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.Query[1..]) : "";

            string queryHash;
            const int MaxQueryStringLength = 48;
            const int MaxQueryHashLength = 16;
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString));
                queryHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }

            var cacheFileName = $"{queryString[0..Math.Min(queryString.Length, MaxQueryStringLength)]}-{queryHash[0..MaxQueryHashLength]}.json";

            return cacheFileName;
        }

        bool IsCacheValid(string cacheFilePath)
        {
            var lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(cacheFilePath);
            return (DateTime.Now - lastWriteTime) <= cacheExpiration;
        }
    }

    private record CacheResponse(HttpStatusCode StatusCode, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> Headers, string Content);

    private static async Task WriteResponseToFileAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, string cacheFilePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
        var headers = response.Headers.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value);

        var cacheResponse = new CacheResponse(response.StatusCode, headers, content);

        using (var fileStream = File.CreateText(cacheFilePath))
        {
            var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(fileStream, cacheResponse);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReadResponseFromFileAsync(string cacheFilePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CacheResponse cacheResponse;

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenText(cacheFilePath))
        {
            var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            cacheResponse = (CacheResponse)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream, typeof(CacheResponse));
        }

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(cacheResponse.StatusCode)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(cacheResponse.Content)
        };

        foreach (var header in cacheResponse.Headers)
        {
            response.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The cache must survive restarts

This from the beginning means that you need some kind out-of-process caching solution. Something like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or analogs can be a good fit, or just store it in some local database (potentially with some background worker handling expiration, etc.).

The rest of requirements - *"I would like to have granular control to flush the cache and/or retention policies"* sound more like some "business" logic level ones and I would recommend to use higher abstraction level rather that `HttpClient`.

As for caching in the `HttpClient` you can write your own caching handler (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers) or [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/08/01/creating-custom-httpclient-handlers.aspx)) or use 3rd party lib like [`HttpClient.Caching`](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/HttpClient.Caching).

Also can be useful:

- [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0)